# Convert trig of angle in degrees to decimal value without a calculator

Tags: trigonometry

Been forever since I did trig, I know how to use my calculator to do it, but I can't remember if there is a way to evaluate $\cos(x)$ without a calculator.  For example:

$\cos(30)$ evaluates to $0.866025$

How would one come up with that value without plugging it into a calculator?

Comment: Do you want just the nice ones (0,30,45,60,90) or all of them?

Comment: Note: to make the degree symbol use ^\circ .  If you don't use it, you mean radians, whether that's what you intend or not.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\cos{30^{\circ}} = \cos{\frac{\pi}{6}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \approx 0.866025$$

since we can convert from degrees into radians by using

$$1^{\circ} = \frac{\pi}{180}$$

---

A decent "mnemonic" to remeber some basic trig function values is the following table:

$$\begin{array}{lr} t & \sin{t} \\ 
0             & \frac{\sqrt{0}}{1} \\ 
\frac{\pi}{6} & \frac{\sqrt{1}}{1} \\
\frac{\pi}{4} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\frac{\pi}{3} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\frac{\pi}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{4}}{2} \end{array}$$

Then $\cos{t}$ can be found from the relation $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

For certain "special angles", like $0$, $\frac\pi6$, $\frac\pi4$, $\frac\pi3$, and $\frac\pi2$, there are very simple expressions for the sine and cosine. For somewhat less special angles, like $\frac\pi5$ and $\frac\pi{10}$, there are somewhat less simple expressions. In the general case, you can always estimate using, for example, $\cos x = 1-\frac {x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots$ and $\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$, or other series expansions.

**Warning:** The series expansions will only work properly for *radian* angle measures. In general, modern mathematicians, physicists, etc., only ever use radian measure. Degrees are yesterday (ancient Babylonian, to be precise).

**Example:** Suppose you want to calculate $\cos 5$. Well, $\cos 5 = \cos (2\pi-5)$, and $2\pi-5\approx6.28-5=1.28$. We see that this is close to $\pi/2\approx 1.57$, so we will use the Taylor expansion about $\pi/2$:
$$\cos x = -(x-\pi/2)+\frac 1{3!}(x-\pi/2)^3-\cdots.$$
Taking just the first term gives $\cos 5\approx 0.29$. My calculator gives $\cos 5 \approx 0.28$, so it's good enough for government work.

Answer (score 0):

The series expansion exists if you really want to get into non-nice values.

$$\cos(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k }{(2 k)!}x^{2 k}$$

Answer (score 0):

A simple derivation is:

An equilateral triangle has all sides equal and all angles equal to $60^{\circ}$.  Therefore a triangle with angle $30^{\circ}$ (which is a bisected equilateral) has a hypotenuse of 1 and a short side of $\frac12$, so $\sin(30^{\circ})=\frac12$.  Since $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$,

$$\cos(30^{\circ}) = \sqrt{1-\frac14} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$.

The advantage of this derivation is that you can, well, derive it (easily).  But, $30^{\circ}$ is obviously an easy angle.  For more general angles, different formula are used depending on the need, for example, Taylor series (as others have shown) and [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) approximations are common on, eg, microcontrollers (where you can't do the fast multiplications required for a Taylor series approach).

Comment: I find it easier to think of the triangle with side length 2.